# What is the official process for persistent tun/tap configuration on Ubuntu 18.04+?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

Ubuntu Server has discarded both `ifconfig` and `/etc/network/interfaces`, and now uses `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d`. Reading [Cloud-Init's network configuration format](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v2.html), I see no mention of tun/tap devices. How should I make a tap device permanent now?